# Buffer Overflow explanation

Tags: c, buffer, overflow

I made this simple password verification program, and I'm trying to overflow the buffer array to change the auth variable to 1 and i managed to do it except I can only change the auth variable to the character 1 and not the decimal 1, how can i do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char buffer[16];
int auth=0;
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

if(strcmp(buffer,"password")==0)
    auth=1;
else
    auth=0;

if(auth)
    printf("Granted");



 return 0;

}
```

Comment: And what do you do to change the `auth` variable? Also, you do know that in C anything non-zero is considered "true", and since the character `'1'` with ASCII encoding is equal to the integer `49` I don't really see any problem (since you don't actually check explicitly for `auth == 1`, what you have know is equivalent to `auth != 0`).

Comment: with my gcc compiler I tried `printf("%x %x\n",&buffer,&auth);` gave me `28feb0 28feac`: bummer :) damn padding optimization? order of variables in the stack is not guaranteed to be the same as declaration.

Comment: the buffer and auth are 28 bytes apart so my input was AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA49, but "GRANTED" was not printed

Comment: @pedrosantos: me neither, see why in my comment.

Comment: the thing is the auth variable was indeed changed to "49" as I wanted with my input, i checked with the debugger, but the if(auth) returned false anyway so granted was not printed

Comment: You have undefined bahaviour here. Debug the assembly code.

Comment: the idea is to trigger undefined behaviour by analyzing assembly & addresses, and if that is possible, inject whatever binary data. With my gcc 4.9 compiler I was not able to do it with that particular piece of code. The hacker must be lucky.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Don't print pointers using `"%x"`, do it using `"%p"`. Also, the pointers must be casted to `void *`. Not using `"%p"` to print (`void *`) pointers is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I know what the problem is, I change the auth variable using the overflow but as execution continues the strcmp(buffer, "password") part changes the auth again to either 1 or 0 that is why it is not working I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following information is derived from runs on my Ubuntu-14.04 system using gcc version 4.8.4 as my compiler and gdb version 7.7.1 as my debugger

First, the buffer overflow happens as a result of the strcpy function, and if you overflow `buf` so that it overwrites the memory location of `auth`, but the following if-else block will overwrite your changes.

Secondly you can see what is happening by looking at the stack in a debugger.  I made a slight modification to you code, by initializing `auth` to `0xbbbbbbbb` (just so I can find here auth is located on the stack).

Setting a break point on main and stepping into the function we can examine the values of the various registers:

```
   (gdb) info reg
   rax            0x0   0
   rbx            0x0   0
   rcx            0x0   0
   rdx            0x7fffffffdf30    140737488346928
   rsi            0x7fffffffdf18    140737488346904
   rdi            0x2   2
   rbp            0x7fffffffde30    0x7fffffffde30
   rsp            0x7fffffffddf0    0x7fffffffddf0
         [... some lines removed ...]
   rip            0x400652  0x400652 <main+37>
   eflags         0x246 [ PF ZF IF ]
   cs             0x33  51
   ss             0x2b  43
   ds             0x0   0
   es             0x0   0
   fs             0x0   0
   gs             0x0   0
```

From this we can see that the stack extends from `0x7fffffffddf0` to `0x7fffffffde30`.  Now stopping right before the call to strcpy, we can take a look at the stack:

```
(gdb) x/76xb $rsp
0x7fffffffddf0: 0x18    0xdf    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffddf8: 0x1d    0x07    0x40    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde00: 0x30    0xde    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde08: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xbb    0xbb    0xbb    0xbb
0x7fffffffde10: 0xd0    0x06    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde18: 0x40    0x05    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde20: 0x10    0xdf    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde28: 0x00    0x2b    0x25    0x07    0xdd    0x7a    0xc0    0x6d
0x7fffffffde30: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde38: 0x45    0x6f    0xa3    0xf7
```

Looking at this, we can see that `auth` is located at a memory address of `0x7fffffffde0c`.

I set as a command line argument `passwordAAAAAAAA111`, and now we can single step across the strcpy call and look at memory again:

```
(gdb) x/76xb $rsp
0x7fffffffddf0: 0x18    0xdf    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffddf8: 0x1d    0x07    0x40    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde00: 0x30    0xde    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde08: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xbb    0xbb    0xbb    0xbb
0x7fffffffde10: 0x70    0x61    0x73    0x73    0x77    0x6f    0x72    0x64
0x7fffffffde18: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffde20: 0x31    0x31    0x31    0x31    0x00    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde28: 0x00    0x2b    0x25    0x07    0xdd    0x7a    0xc0    0x6d
0x7fffffffde30: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffde38: 0x45    0x6f    0xa3    0xf7
```

(gdb)

From this, we can see that the value of `auth` has not be touched (notice the four 0xbb still in memory starting at 0x7fffffffde0c).  Also we can now see where the password is stored in memory, it starts at `0x7fffffffde10`.  The four 'A's that I used are where the four 0x41s are and the four '1's that I used are where the four 0x31s are

So, on my system I do not see a way that you would be able to overflow into the `auth` variable.

Finally, the question that you originally raised, remember that the command line arguments are treated as a character array, so passing in something line `AAAA1` on the command line will result in the array [0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x31] being passed to your program.  What you want your program to receive is actually [0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00] (assuming 32-bit, little endian architecture).  There are two issues that you will face,
1. 0x01 is a non-printable character
2. 0x00 being the null terminator will stop the string input at the first null.

There is not alot you can do about the issue 2, with just a simple input; however as others have suggested the solution around issue 1 is to create a driver program that builds the input buffer the way that you want and then passes that to the program.

Comment: I almost forgot that there's no way at all to inject a 0 (null) character as arguments are null-terminated, so if you want to inject some data or code, you will have to do without the zero character. Good and thourough explanation.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but in my program the auth variable os allocated after the buffer so i can overflow it. I t is the issue with the non printable character

Answer (score 1):

On windows (resp. Linux), create a bat (resp shell) file like this:

```
a 0123456789ABCDEFG
```

(a being the name of your executable)

[image]

Then, edit it with an hex editor and change the last `G` to 01 hex value, save.

If (I say if) you can make sure that the address of your integer value comes after the char buffer (which I could not do using my gcc, since the compiler locates its variable with an implementation-based order), run this script and you will see that the \001 char is passed at the end of first argument.

Note: there's no way at all to pass a 0 (null) character as arguments are null-terminated, so if you want to inject some data or code, you will have to do without the zero character.

Comment: im running debian